# How to arrange html footer elements to break automatically

Tags: html, css

I have following footer on my website

[image]

with this html

```
<div class="footer_wrapper">
    <div class="top">
        <div class="footer_menu_block_float">
            <h1>Footer section</h1>
            <ul>
                <li>One</li>
                <li>Two</li>
                <li>Three</li>
                <li>Three</li>
                <li>Three</li>
                <li>Three</li>
                <li>Three</li>
                <li>Three</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="bottom"></div>
</div>​
```

The height of the `footer_menu_block_float` is fixed.

```
.footer_wrapper .top div.footer_menu_block_float {
    height: 140px;
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    margin: 10px 20px 0px 10px;
}
```

As you can see some text is hidden. Is it possible to continue on the right side when the bottom of the footer is reached? E.g. from three, four would go beside one and five beside two and so on. Any idea how to do that? Maybe I should use divs?

Comment: There's no reason to use another HTML element. All HTML elements are the same in CSS' eyes (ie they can all be styled equally (with the exception of some weird elements like form inputs etc)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found this solution very useful

```
<div class="footer_wrapper">
        <div class="top">
            <div class="footer_menu_block_float">
                <h1>Footer section</h1>
                <div>One</div>
                <div>Two</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <div class="bottom"></div>
    </div>
```

With

```
.footer_wrapper .top div.footer_menu_block_float div{
    float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
height: 140px;
```

by

```
min-height: 140px;
```

so the minimum height is 200px but can gets larger

Have fun :)

Answer (score 0):

My idea is to make two `ul`s and float them. See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/T5822/